# understanding this snippet of code from Kotlin

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

i am working with the nordic library for BLE in android studio. i copied this bit of java code into kotlin from their documentation. however, the kotlin equivalent is sort of difficult for me to understand. i have not seen syntax like it before. and i am also getting some warning signs on dataCharacteristicCallback and dataRead which i do not know how to debug.  especially the "dataCharacteristicCallback = object" in the function declaration really confuses me. i feel that this is an application of a lambda expression or functions as first-class citizen, and that android studio's java to kotlin conversion maybe a bit imprecise here.

here is the original java bit.

```
private final BlinkyButtonDataCallback buttonCallback = new BlinkyButtonDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonStateChanged(@NonNull final BluetoothDevice device,
                                         final boolean pressed) {
            log(LogContract.Log.Level.APPLICATION, "Button " + (pressed ? "pressed" : "released"));
            buttonState.setValue(pressed);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidDataReceived(@NonNull final BluetoothDevice device,
                                          @NonNull final Data data) {
            log(Log.WARN, "Invalid data received: " + data);
        }
    };
```

here is the kotlin-equivalent

```
        private val dataRead: dataCharacteristicCallback = object : dataRead() {
            fun onButtonStateChanged(device: BluetoothDevice, pressed: Boolean) {
                log(LogContract.Log.Level.APPLICATION, "Button " + if (pressed) "pressed" else "released")
                buttonState.setValue(pressed)
            }

            fun onInvalidDataReceived(device: BluetoothDevice,
                                      data: Data) {
                log(Log.WARN, "Invalid data received: $data")
            }
        }
```

Comment: `object : Foo` is how you declare anonymous classes (with super type) in kotlin.
Replace `object : dataRead()`  with `object : BlinkyButtonDataCallback()`.
You also going to need to add `override` modifier to both methods in your class`

Comment: interesting, i thought kotlin conversion would take care of those things. but thanks, i will read more into anonymous classes. dataRead is actually the function I am using the sample code for. so in my case the object is dataRead